# Laravel back() with controller parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently building a Laravel App with a form. When the form is displayed, I want to save it in the database, do my controller action does something like this:

```
public function submit_form(Offer $offer, Request $request){
    $offer->click();    // This updates the database
    return view('offers.submit_form', compact('offers'))->with('APP_NAME', env('APP_NAME'));
}
```

When there is an error in the form, I want to go back to the previous page, like the following:

```
public function submit(Offer $offer, Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [...]); // Some validation
    if($validator->fails()){
        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    $offer->submit();
    return view('offers.submit', compact('offers'))->with('APP_NAME', env('APP_NAME'));
}
```

Here is my problem: when I go back, I want to be able to send a parameter to the `submit_form` **controller** so that it doesn't update the database every time there is an error in the form.

I want to be able to write something like this in the `submit_form` controller:

```
if($some_argument) $offer->click();
```

What is the best way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Laravel handles this "automagically", see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic. If you have something like `$validatedData = $request->validate([yourvalidationrules])` you can just continue to store your data, any errors/redirects are handled by Laravel

Comment: Yes I know that but I cannot retrieve the errors (or the fact that there is an error) in the controller of the page (I can only get them in the view)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query string in back() method:

```
return back()->with('key', 'some_data')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

and then retrieve it as session variable:

```
if(session('key')) $offer->click();
```

Comment: that wouldn't add a query string, it would flash that data to the session .... but that variable won't be available by the time they get to the controller as there was already a request for the view and the next request is submitting the form, the flash variable only lasts until the end of the next request (which would be the request that ends up with the view returned)

Comment: Yes, @lagbox is right, I have tried this and it does not work... Any idea on how to do it in a clean way?